# Writing or Copying Visual C++ console output to text file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, include, perceptual-sdk

I am working with Intel Perceptual Computing SDK Voice Recognition Module. Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional, the SDK sample perceives the dictation and after processing the voice input prints it on the console window. All i want to do is to copy the output printed on console window and write it in a `.txt` file. I am following the general way but somehow the text written in file is just some numbers.

```
// Callback for recognized commands and alerts
class MyHandler: public PXCVoiceRecognition::Recognition::Handler, public    PXCVoiceRecognition::Alert::Handler
```

{
    public:
    MyHandler(std::vector &commands)
    { this->commands=commands; }

```
virtual void PXCAPI OnRecognized(PXCVoiceRecognition::Recognition *cmd) 
{
  wprintf_s(L"\nRecognized: <%s>\n", (cmd->label>=0)?commands[cmd->label]:cmd-    >dictation); //this line prints the dictated statement//
  // writing to a text file
  printf("Writing to the txt file...");
  std::ofstream out("c:\\MyVoice.txt");
  out<<cmd->dictation;
}

protected:
std::vector<pxcCHAR*> commands;
```

};

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
// Create session
PXCSmartPtr<PXCSession> session;
pxcStatus sts = PXCSession_Create(&session);
if (sts < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) {
wprintf_s(L"Failed to create the PXCSession\n");
return 3;
}
// Parse command line
UtilCmdLine cmdl(session);
if (!cmdl.Parse(L"-file-iuid-grammar-sdname-realtime-eos",argc, argv)) return 1;

// Create PXCVoiceRecognition instance
PXCSmartPtr<PXCVoiceRecognition> vc;
sts=session->CreateImpl(cmdl.m_iuid, PXCVoiceRecognition::CUID, (void **)&vc);
if (sts<PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) 
{
 wprintf_s(L"Failed to create PXCVoiceRecognition\n");
 return 3;
}

// Find and initilize capture module
UtilCaptureFile capture(session,cmdl.m_recordedFile,false);
if (cmdl.m_sdname) capture.SetFilter(cmdl.m_sdname);

 // Query PXCVoiceRecognition profile
 PXCVoiceRecognition::ProfileInfo profile;
 for (int i=0;;i++) 
 {
  sts=vc->QueryProfile(i, &profile);
  sts=capture.LocateStreams(&profile.inputs);
  return 3;
 }
if (cmdl.m_realtime >= 0) capture.SetRealtime(cmdl.m_realtime);
// Set PXCVoiceRecognition profile
if (cmdl.m_eos) profile.endOfSentence = cmdl.m_eos;
sts=vc->SetProfile(&profile);

// Grammar intialization
pxcUID grammar = 0;
if (cmdl.m_grammar.size()<0)
{
  wprintf_s(L"Dictation Mode\n");
}

vc->SetGrammar(grammar);  
// SubscribeRecognition
MyHandler handler(cmdl.m_grammar);
vc->SubscribeRecognition(80, &handler); 
vc->SubscribeAlert(&handler);

// Processing loop
PXCSmartPtr<PXCAudio> audio;
PXCSmartSPArray sps(3);
wprintf_s(L"Press any key to exit\n");

while (!_kbhit()) 
{
  sts = capture.ReadStreamAsync(audio.ReleaseRef(),sps.ReleaseRef(0));
  sts=vc->ProcessAudioAsync(audio,sps.ReleaseRef(1));
  sps.SynchronizeEx();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly

Comment: @Sean I had big trouble formatting it in this way. It is not allowing me to post with changes.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `>` to redirect the output of the command run by Visual Studio.  Add it to the command arguments by selecting your project in the solution explorer and clicking PROJECT->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging.  Then enter `> output.txt` into the Command Arguments.  After you run your application, the file will appear in the Working Directory - which by default is the same directory as your .sln files.

Comment: Thank you. This works for a normal application. Somehow when I do the same for this code of voice recognition posted above, The console is not giving out anything. Without this changes, it is working fine and giving me outputs. But does nothing for > output.txt except making an empty txt file.

Comment: It is possible your output is going to stderr instead of stdout?  To capture stderr you use `2> output.txt` instead of `>`.  You can also combine both into the same file with `> output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Good. But there's a twist. The program is executing perfectly and making a txt file too. But it's not writing the console output to the txt file.

Comment: (If this is of some help)I guess my output is in unicode stream because it is only printed on console if I am using wprinf_s. It wont working with printf or printf_s. @Rastaban

Answer (score 3):

I think he is simply suggesting to run your executable and direct it to a file:
C:\.exe > C:\output.txt

Here is a link about [redirection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you could produce the output correctly in the console window, then you can just run the executable with a command line argument like `> c:\result.txt` to redirect the standard output to a file (I'm assuming you are on Windows since you have the visual-c++ tag), thus you don't need to change your code at all (everything you put to `cout` will be written to the file specified in the argument).  If you are using the Visual Studio GUI, command line arguments can be specified in the project's properties page, otherwise you could just type the command in a console window by hand.

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 7. Can you please give me a link which details the method you just described?