# Copying (not redirecting) Visual C++ console output to text file while still viewing the output in console window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

a variety on this question has been asked and answered
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709463/3906864

I followed the above linked answer and did the following

`">log.txt"`

that argument was added here

[image]

This allows the console output to be redirected from console to file, and the console window remains blank without anything displayed in it.

but i can't find a way to view the output in console while still simultaneously  saving a copy  to a txt file.
any ideas ?

Comment: One way would be to write a 'tee' that replaces `cout` (or `cerr`). You can do this by writing you own `ostream` and `rdbuf` it. Tips [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/cpp-streambufs)

Answer (score 0):

you need a version of `tee`. Powershell has `Tee-Object` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx)

An example from link

```
get-process | tee-object -filepath C:\Test1\testfile2.txt
```

The above will output both to terminal and to the file