# Visual Studio, How to SEPARATE the input and the output IN C++ Competitive Programming

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, console, c++17

I want to separate the input and the output this is [MY CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ANhI.png)
and I want Like this [WANTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXrWJ.png) OR in seperate files

Comment: Just put  your cout statements at the end instead of between each input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your answers in a container (vector, array, etc) and print all of them when no new inputs are expected.

Keep in mind that in competitive programming, most of the times the judge doesn't care *when* you produce your output, unless specifically said so.

Comment: No I don't want to make vector or array because it is not easy to make like that I know that the jude doesn't car about the seperation of input and output but I want seperate them because if input is bit large I can't seperate them by my eye and the input and the output be mixed.

Comment: Seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709463/12073317) is what you're looking for. You can put your inputs in a file too, using `<` instead of `>`.